# Persisting cart Items on my e-commerce website

Tags: mongodb, session, react-redux

I'm planning on an e-commerce website and would like some help!

The functionality I want is that whenever a user logs in, I will use the user's email address to fetch from my MongoDB database to **retrieve all of the user's cart information** (what the user has put in his/her cart from last time). However, I worry that if the user accidentally closes their tab, or closes their window, and visits the website again, then I would need to fetch from my database again to get the cart items. My question is that would it be better to store the cart item on a local storage or session storage. And then, **once the user goes to the checkout page**, I then store all of the cart items back to database. In that way, I don't need to store to and retrieve from the database everytime the user adds an item to the cart.

I'm using React/MongoDB. This is my first time building a e-commerce website and I would like to know how other people usually handle this problem, and whether local storage, session storage, or there are other ways to handle this!

Comment: I'm no expert, but I use express session to store the cart. I'm not sure it is common to store the cart information separately in the database, but I guess there could be use-cases where you'd want to have that data for some deep analytics. Hope this helps!

Comment: that is a good suggestion! Thank you ~